# Just started learning programming with python, stuck at a part in my code?

Tags: python

```
ShirtNumber = input('How many shirts would you like to order?')

if ShirtNumber >= '12':
    Discount = '0.70'
    Shipping = '0'
elif ShirtNumber >= '6':
    Discount = '0.80'
    Shipping = '8.99'
elif ShirtNumber >= '3':
    Discount = '0.90'
    Shipping = '8.99'

TotalCost = (ShirtNumber * Discount) * 12.99 + Shipping


print('Your total cost comes out to:$ ', TotalCost)
```

Error is:

```
TotalCost = (ShirtNumber * Discount) * 12.99 + Shipping
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

I just started programming so I don't have the greatest understanding yet and its only my first assignment. I've reviewed my notes and can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

The program is based around ordering shirts with larger numbers being ordered are discounted. If you have any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also have another look at your logic and try to reason what would happen if I would try to order zero, one or two shirts.

Comment: A little random tip, variable and function names should be `under_scored`, not `CamelCased`. Only classes should be `CamelCased`.

Answer (score 2):

`ShirtNumber` is a string, you can't do math operations between two strings. You may want to convert it to an int first:

```
ShirtNumber = int(input('How many shirts would you like to order?'))
```

Similar, every number in your code should be just number, without quotes, like

```
if ShirtNumber >= 12:
    Discount = 0.70
    Shipping = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing strings and numbers.

As a rule of thumb, anything you do maths on - add, subtract, divide etc - is a number.

Numbers don't have quotes - `discount = 0.8`

Most other things are strings, even if they contain digits. For example, phone numbers are strings - you will never add or subtract phone numbers.

Strings look like this: `phonenumber='095801374'`.

Strings can be joined together (using the '+' sign) - '1' + '2' = '12'.

Anything you read with input() will return a string (even if you know it is a number). You can convert a string to a number, just by casting it, like this: `ShirtNumber=int(ShirtNumber)`. Note that, if, when asked for the number of shirts, they typed `five` (instead of `5`), then you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attempting to use a string in arithmetic.

The function `input()` will return a value of type *string*. Thus, in order to do arithmetic with `ShirtNumber`, you must convert it to either an integer or a floating point number. To do the former, you use the function `int()`. Documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int.

So in your code, you would do

```
ShirtNumber = int(input('How many shirts would you like to order?'))
```

Something you don't have to do, but might also like to think about, is to verify first that the input you've received is in the form of an integer. For that, you can use the function `isdigit()` found at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html.

If the input is *not* in the form of an integer, you might want to ask the user to re-input their answer. To do that, you can use a while loop, like this:

```
answerFound = false
badAnswerGiven = false
while not(answerFound):

    if badAnswerGiven:
        print('The number of shirts must be an integer. E.g. 6. ')
    ShirtNumber = input('How many shirts would you like to order?')

    if isdigit(ShirtNumber):
        ShirtNumber = int(ShirtNumber)
        answerFound = true
    else:
        badAnswerGiven = true

# rest of the program follows
```

One last note: it's common practice to make the first character of a variable name lowercase. This is up to you, but that is the most common convention (though less common in some languages, like C#). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Letter_case_and_numerals

Answer (score 0):

Many of these answers say input returns string. This is not necessarily true...

input accepts data from the user and tries to evaluate it. and raw_input returns 'str'.

Your problem is your Discount variable. That one is 'str'

Discount = '0.70'

Discount = 0.7 would be float and then you can multiply your ShirtNumber and Discount

```
input([prompt])
Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

You can check the type of your variables in the interpreter by using type function:

```
type(Discount)
type(ShirtNumber)
```

Try that after you type in your code into the interpreter.

input would return string if the user enters literally

```
'1'
```

But if they enter

```
1
```

it would return 'int'

Comment: I suspect the OP is using Python 3, where `raw_input()` has been renamed `input()` and there is not a `raw_input()` function. See [PEP 3111](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/#specification).